# Finding the adjoint of matrix of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-calculus, contraction-operator

I am working in book "A Hilbert Space Problem Book" by Paul R. Halmos.

When I try to show each problem in detail, I got in stuck with problem 132 , page 72. It states that:

"If $A$ is a contraction (that means $\|A\| \le 1$), then $1-AA*$ is positive (A* is the adjoint operator of A); call it A'. 
Assertion: the operator matrix
$$M(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
A & A'\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
is a partial isometry. Proof: Check that MM*M=M.
"

I really confuse what the adjoint of $M$ (I mean $M*$) is. How to find it in general?

Moreover, How to apply to check that $MM*M=M$?

Could you please help me to understand it deeply? Thank you so much.

Comment: $I-AA^*$ is positive semi definite.

Comment: I know that and I can do it. However, I would like to find $M*$, the adjoint of matrix $M$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, in most cases, $M^* = \overline{M}^t$, here $\overline{}$ is the complex conjugate.

Comment: Actually, I confuse because it is the matrix of operators. That means, each entry is an operator. How can we find the conjugate transform of each entry?